# avoiding queries in loops for gradebook

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am making a gradebook and while the code below works, it is awfully slow. The first Column for the table is each students name, and then each cell afterwords corresponds to a specific question and shows what the students answer was. Not each student will have answered the given question.

Right now I have a loop and for each user a loop inside of that loop for each question.

Each question has a unique id, in a separate table each answer has a corresponding user id and a corresponding question id.

I have looked for similar posts with no luck, I have only been working with php for a few months so any advice will be much appreciated.

Questions

| id | question | choice 1 | choice 2 | choice 3 | choice 4 | correctAnswer | categoryId |

Answers

| id | questionId | userId | studentAnswer |

Users

| id | firstName |

Thanks

```
//Select all questions from a specific category $mid defined by user
    $questionQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE mid = $mid");
    $questionCount = mysql_num_rows($questionQuery);

        //Blank space in table above users
            echo "<tr><td></td>";

            //Question Number, each category has a different number of questions
            for ($q = 0; $q < $questionCount; $q++){
                echo "<td>" . ($q+1) . "</td>";
            }

            echo "</tr>";


    //Select all students for a given teacher
    $userQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE teacherId = $userid ORDER BY `block`, `lastName`");
    $userCount = mysql_num_rows($userQuery);

        for($s = 0; $s < $userCount; $s++){
            $currentUserId = mysql_result($userQuery, $s, 0);

                //Echo student's name
                echo "<tr class='user" . ($s%2) ."'><td>" . mysql_result($userQuery, $s, 1) . "</td>";


                //Load current question id
                for ($q = 0; $q < $questionCount; $q++){
                    $questionNum = mysql_result($questionQuery, $q, 0);

                    //Selects students answer from answers database for above question
                    $answerQuery = mysql_query("SElECT * FROM answers WHERE questionId = $questionNum AND userId = $currentUserId");
                    $answerCount = mysql_num_rows($answerQuery);

                        //If no answers move on to next cell
                        if($answerCount == 0){
                            echo "<td></td>";
                        }
                        else{
                            $currentAnswer = mysql_result($answerQuery, 0, 3);
                            $correctAnswer = mysql_result($questionQuery, $q, 6);

                        if ($currentAnswer == $correctAnswer){
                            echo "<td class='right'><div id='parent'>" . $currentAnswer . "</div></td>";
                        }
                        else{
                            echo "<td class='wrong'><div id='parent'>" . $currentAnswer . "</div></td>";
                        }
            }
                   }
                   echo "</tr>";
      }
```

Comment: Please give a description of your data model. I don’t want to have to _guess_ that from your SQL statements.

Comment: you are making too many queries... change this one: SElECT * FROM answers WHERE questionId = $questionNum AND userId = $currentUserId to this SElECT * FROM answers WHERE userId = $currentUserId then loop over all the answers and fill in the row.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I added the structure of the relevant tables